# JSP escapeHTML for all request parameters

Tags: jsp

Do there exists an effective way to escape (f.e. escapeHTML etc.) all request parameters at one time? What is best practice?

Comment: What have you tried ? what do you say as effective way and please elaborate . one liner questions are not descriptive

Comment: "effective way to escape (f.e. escapeHTML etc" - can you provide an example on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I can escape each parameter like this:

String escaped = escapeStringEscapeUtils.escapeXml();

But I'd prefer like this:

EscapeUtils.escapeXml(request.getParameter);

so that I didnt need escape all request params seperate...

Comment: so you need something which escapes the request attribute in an single event ?

Comment: yes; Thats exactly what I want.

Comment: No you cant do like that as it is the collection of entire request. Alternatively you can do that in the jsp with `JSTL COUT` tag as it escapes html by default